# Add count of element for each groups within a list in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
The_list=["A","B","D"]

Groups Values
G1     A
G1     B
G1     C
G1     D
G2     A
G2     B
G2     A
G3     A
G3     D
G4     Z
G4     D
G4     E
G4     C
```

And I would like to add for each `Groups` the number of  `Values` element that are within **The_list**, and add this number within a `New_column`

Here I should then get;

```
Groups Values New_column
G1     A      3
G1     B      3
G1     C      3
G1     D      3
G2     A      2
G2     B      2
G2     A      2
G3     A      1
G3     D      1
G4     Z      0
G4     D      0
G4     E      0
G4     C      0
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Here is the table in dict format if it can helps:

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G2', 7: 'G3', 8: 'G3', 9: 'G4', 10: 'G4', 11: 'G4', 12: 'G4'}, 'Values': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'D', 9: 'Z', 10: 'D', 11: 'E', 12: 'C'}}
```

Comment: The expected output seems incorrect corresponding to given input?

Comment: I checked and it is correct .. What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case do `transform` after `isin` check

```
df['new'] = df['Values'].isin(The_list).groupby(df['Groups']).transform('sum')
Out[37]: 
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     2
8     2
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    1
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```